# Excel Hyperlink adding redirectURL

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I'm creating a hyperlink in excel

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.redacted.com/index.html?Display=GroupMeetings/index","link")
```

When I click on this link it changes the Url to

```
https://www.redacted.com/index.html?redirectURL=Display%3DGroupMeetings%2Findex
```

if I change the URL to have `?Displayy=` with two `y`'s it does not add the `redirectURL` attribute. I cannot find any documentation about why this is added. Anyone know why?

The end goal is to deep launch users to specific pages within the application via a hyperlink in excel.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the site it's self redirecting you when you have a "Display" param? If you just type https://www.redacted.com/index.html?Display=GroupMeetings/index into your browser, does it still redirect you? If so, you know it is nothing to do with Excel.

Comment: @Gravitate That's the first thing I tried. If I copy the URL directly into the browser and I'm logged in it takes me directly to the page I need.

Comment: What if you copy the URL directly into the browser and aren't logged in? Does that take you to the redirected address? Or another page entirely?

Comment: @Gravitate It takes me to the login page, which is what is expected. If users aren't logged in they won't have access to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Do the users need to be authenticated to view the pages you are sending them to?

If so the cause may be this (taken from this answer on super user https://superuser.com/a/445431/154198):

> Clicking a URL in Excel seems to open it in your default browser. But that's not really true. Before opening it in your browser, Excel first runs Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery. This uses a Windows/Internet Explorer component to determine if the URL works. (It does not identify itself as Internet Explorer, but as "User Agent: Microsoft Office Existence Discovery".) And if the results are (somehow) okay then it will open the result of that check in your default browser.

Microsoft have issued a fix for this KB218153 - which can be found here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/218153/error-message-when-clicking-hyperlink-in-office-cannot-locate-the-inte

This may not be your specific problem, but it is at least worth knowing about.

Comment: Users do need to be logged in to access the site. I installed the fix, but the issue still exists :-/